# Fastest way to create local copy of live InnoDB MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, restore, mysql-workbench

We have a `MySQL database (InnoDB)` on our `live Ubuntu 12.04 server` which has grown quite large (25gb+).

Every month or so we need to copy this database to our development machines to work on locally.

Previously we have exported the database with `MySQL Workbench`, downloaded the `.sql` file to our development machines, and then imported it, again with `MySQL Workbench`. The problem is now the database is so large, we can't do the restore quick enough for it to finish over the weekend! So on Monday morning we have a half-imported database to work with.

What do other people do in this situation?

The only solution I can think of so far, is doing the restore to an unused machine, then `copying` the data to all our development machines (5 of them). Would this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a backup from the live MySQL with [Xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup).

Percona provides deb repository for Ubuntu. To install the repo for Ubuntu 12.04 follow [instructions](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation/apt_repo.html):

- Install the key:

  ```
  # apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
  ```
- Add the source file:

  ```
  # cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/percona.list 
  deb http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
  deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
  ```
- Update the local cache:

  ```
  # apt-get update
  ```
- And install xtrabackup:

  ```
  # apt-get install xtrabackup
  ```

To take a copy of the database run following:

```
    # innobackupex .
```

It will create a directory like "2010-03-13_02-42-44". Copy that directory to a development box, apply redo log:

```
    # innobackupex --apply-log /data/backups/2010-03-13_02-42-44/
```

Then the directory is ready to use. Copy it back to MySQL datadir and fix ownership:

```
    # cp /data/backups/2010-03-13_02-42-44/ /var/lib/mysql
    # chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Then you may start MySQL.

More details you can find on http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/how-tos.html

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, some of the development machines are Windows. Do you think the alpha version of XtraBackup would be up to the job (just for the restoring part)?

Comment: no, please don't use alpha version. It is way too old and now Xtrabackup doesn't support Windows.
As workaround you may prepare the backup copy on a Linux machine (--apply-log step) and copy the data directory to the Windows machine.

Comment: Would this bring any advantages over just importing a mysqldump to a different machine and then copying that across? Would that even work?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that xtrabakup is as fast as file copy while after mysql dump you have to replay all SQL commands to restore the database

Comment: FINALLY got round to trying this months later! Works brilliantly! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you may consider setting up replications from the main server to your dev machines. It would require to have a direct connection from your master to the slaves (the dev machines), but it doesn't need to be permanent. If you connect it once a month then the master will replicate only the changes, which should still be much faster.

I doubt any other backup solution can do better than MySQL Workbench (which uses mysqldump behind the scenes). All solutions doing a normal backup have to dump the content and restore it later. The only alternative is to replicate changes (or move binary datafiles, which is a bad idea and may not work in the future).

Comment: We did consider replication, but would we not get issues with duplicate keys etc? Especially on auto-increment fields? Unless there's a way of saying overwrite any data which differs slightly.

Comment: auto_increment columns are handled correctly in replication. There's a special page that discusses some (earlier) problems in that area: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html

Comment: I down voted because a) replication won't help here unless the dev databases are read only, which is unlikely; b) at least three ways to backup and restore mysql are faster than mysqldump: cold backup, LVM snapshot , Xtrabakup